# Using predict_proba() instead predict() in Neuraxle Pipeline with OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, neuraxle

I'm trying to setup a **Neuraxle Pipeline** that uses sklearns OneVsRestClassifier (*OVR*).

Every valid step in a Neuraxle pipeline has to implement the `fit()` and `transform()` methods.

In order to use sklearns pipeline steps, Neuraxle uses a **SKLearnWrapper** that maps the OVRs `predict()` method to the `transform()` method of the SKLearnWrapper.

1. Is there a way to modify this behavior so that the `predict_proba()` method is mapped to the OVRs `transform()` method instead?
2. Or is there another way of retrieving the calculated probabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good question !

We already have something to solve this.

Suppose you code a class like this:

```
class MyWrapper(BaseStep): 

    def transform(self, data_inputs): 
        return sigmoid(data_inputs)

    def predict_proba(self, data_inputs): 
        return data_inputs
```

You could do as follow:

```
step = MyWrapper()
```

Then, once you're ready to replace the method, use [Neuraxle's mutate](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html?highlight=mutate#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.mutate) function:

```
step = step.mutate(new_method='predict_proba', method_to_assign_to='transform')
```

And then, whenever `.transform()` will be called, the `predict_proba` method will be called instead. The mutate will work even if your `step` is wrapped (nested) deeper within other steps.

Note that we should probably modify the sklearn wrapper to allow this. I've added the issue here:
https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle/issues/368

So until this issue is fixed, you could do `class MySKLearnWrapper(SKLearnWrapper): ...` (inheriting from SKLearnWrapper to modify it) and def the `predict_proba` by yourself like it was suggested here: https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle/pull/363/files